# RavenDB: Can't get multi-term facet to return original value on a field that uses SimpleAnalyzer

Tags: c#, ravendb, facet

I'm using RavenDB 2 Client.

I want my users to be able to search by Category and return products.  For a category name of `High Heels` I want the user to be able to search `heels` and get back products with category `High Heels`.

I set up my `CategoryName` field in the index as follows:

```
Analyzers.Add(x => x.CategoryName, "SimpleAnalyzer");
```

The problem comes when I want to show the facets for `CategoryName`. In stead of returning `high heels` hits 1, it returns `high` hits 1 and `heels` hits 1.

I understand why it's doing this and I've tried using:

```
Stores.Add(x => x.CategoryName, FieldStorage.Yes);
```

but with no success when using it with facetes.

**So my question is**, how do I get the facet to return `high heels` instead of `high` and `heels` on a field that usses `SimpleAnalyzer`?

My Code is below:

My Index

```
public class ProductIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Product,ProductIndex.ProductIndexItem>
{
    public class ProductIndexItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }

    public ProductIndex()
    {
        Map = products => from product in products
                          from category in product.Categories
                          select new
                              {
                                  product.Name,
                                  CategoryName = category.Name
                              };

        Stores.Add(x => x.CategoryName, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Analyzers.Add(x => x.CategoryName, "SimpleAnalyzer");
    }
}
```

My Test

```
    [Test]
    public void MultiTermCategoryTest()
    {
        var product = new Product
            {
                Name = "MyProductName",
                Categories = new List<Category>
                    {
                        new Category
                            {
                                Name = "High Heels",
                            }
                    }
            };

        _session.Store(product);
        _session.SaveChanges();

        var query = _session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Product>("ProductIndex")
                            .WaitForNonStaleResults()
                            .Search("CategoryName", "heels");

        var products = query.ToList();
        var facets = query.SelectFields<Facet>("CategoryName").ToFacets("facets/ProdctFacets");

        // Check that product has been returned
        Assert.That(products.Count, Is.EqualTo(1), "Product count is incorrect.");

        // Check that facet has been returned
        Assert.That(facets.Results.Count, Is.EqualTo(1), "Facet Results count is incorrect");
        var facetResult = facets.Results.FirstOrDefault();

        // Check that factes are what I want
        Assert.That(facetResult.Key, Is.EqualTo("CategoryName"));

         // ** Fails here returning a count of 2** 
        Assert.That(facetResult.Value.Values.Count, Is.EqualTo(1), "Facet.Value.Values count is incorrect");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer thanks to Ayende Rahien's advice.

Turns out you can't do the above the way I was trying.

I had to have two fields in the index, one for indexing and one for storing the original value.  So I changed my index to the following:

```
public class ProductIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Product,ProductIndex.ProductIndexItem>
{
    public class ProductIndexItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public string CategoryNameAnalyzed { get; set; }
    }

    public ProductIndex()
    {
        Map = products => from product in products
                          from category in product.Categories
                          select new
                              {
                                  product.Name,
                                  CategoryName = category.Name,
                                  CategoryNameAnalyzed = category.Name,
                              };

        Stores.Add(x => x.CategoryName, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Analyzers.Add(x => x.CategoryNameAnalyzed, "SimpleAnalyzer");
    }
}
```

And my query changed to:

```
var query = _session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Product>("ProductIndex")
                            .WaitForNonStaleResults()
                            .Search("CategoryNameAnalyzed", "heels");
var products = query.ToList();
var facets = query.ToFacets("facets/ProdctFacets");
```

I hope this helps someone else.